# Why does split(".") fail? java

Tags: java

I've written the following code:

```
String[] arr = ((String) "asd.asd").split(".");
```

and `arr=[]`. Why?

Comment: Because the split function expects a regular expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a regular expression as an argument. "." in regular means "any character".

Instead, use:

```
 String[] arr = "asd.asd".split("\\.");
```

The backslashes escape the special meaning of the "." character in a regular expression.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 2):

`split()` accepts a regex. you should escape the `.` use `"\\."` . In regex `.` is a special character (Meta character) which means *match any character*.

Answer (score 1):

You must double escape the `.`, otherwise the regular expression represents it as "any character".

Also, you don't need to cast "asd.asd" as `String`.

```
String[] arr = "asd.asd".split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because '.' is a special character. You need to escape it by writing it like this `'\\.'`

Comment: No, forward slashes really aren't going to help. And "special character" really doesn't describe what's going on.